# java- Array reference assignment

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just picking up java. I tried something but it won't compile:

```
int[] arr = methodThatReturnsIntArray();
```

But this one works:

```
int[] arr = null;
arr = methodThatReturnsIntArray();
```

Why is it so? Isn't that array variables are just references (or pointers)?
Many thanks!

Comment: What does it say it first case?

Comment: What is the precise error message, and in what context is that code snippet?

Comment: it worked fine for me, show us the code surrounding the assignment.

Comment: Does the method return an `int` array or an `Integer` array?

Comment: There was something wrong with the return value of the method... Now I see both will work.

Comment: could you please post the methodThatReturnsIntArray() code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are correct and should not give compilation error provided that the `methodThatReturnsIntArray()` is returning a valid integer array

for example:

```
int[] methodThatReturnsIntArray(){
    return new int[2];
}
```

Comment: There was something wrong with the return value of the method... Now I see both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are correct , please check example below.

```
public class testItClass {

public int[] methodThatReturnsIntArray(){
    int a[]=new int[10];
    return a;

}
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] arr = new testItClass().methodThatReturnsIntArray();
}
}
```

Hope it will this helps :)